# Is there any php code to allow access on a page just from homepage? otherwise redirect to home

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hello guys im new to php, maybe my question is just too simple.
But I wanna know if there is a way to redirect users who open **www.example.com/page.php** to **www.example.com**
But if they try to open the page from www.example.com , then no redirects and the page loads completly.
I actually have a from on my home page which it has a button on it and when users click the button they enters www.example.com/page.php
But I dont want the users to access www.example.com/page.php without clicking on button.
Can someone show me an example with php codes?

Comment: You should put some configuration in `.htaccess`

Comment: on page.php check form post values exist

Comment: also it can be achieve by the session

Comment: all you have to do is to check that the seesion variable is set or not. on the page.php

Comment: using sessions wont check if the form is posted.

Comment: What are the configurations I have to use on .htaccess?

Comment: @MohammadExploit .htaccess has nothing to do with it, see the other comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to use a conditional statement on page.php to check if data has been posted (value of your button).

Code would look like -

```
<?php

if ( (!isset($_POST)) && ($_POST['buttonName'] != 'postedButtonValue' )){
    header('Location: http://www.example.com');
    exit();
}

// continue script below...

?>
```

Comment: Hey thanks i guess im choosing this one. how can I check if data is posted or not? im using <input type="submit"> for sending data , I dont have a button and a button name actually. I have 2 other inputs btw, 1 for username and 1 for password.

Comment: There are several ways - One way would be to add at least a name to your submit <input type="submit" name="submit"> and then replace ($_POST['buttonName'] != 'postedButtonValue' ) with (!isset($_POST['submit']) - This will then check to see if the submit input has been posted. Or check to see if the username or password values are set.

Comment: @MohammadExploit Let me know if you need any further clarification on this issue... Happy to assist.

Answer (score -1):

Multiple things you can do here:

option 1:
    Set up a small PHP script on the homepage that sets a session variable to true so for example:
`<?php $_SESSION['cameFromHomepage'] = true; ?>` 
Then when someone loads the page, look for that session variable and check if it's true, or even set to begin with, if it is true, continue, else redirect to homepage.

Option 2:
Use cookies, it's the same idea as option one but instead of session you use the cookie.

Depeding on why you want your users to come from the homepage there may be more options, like for example using a GET parameter like this: `$_GET['cameFromHomePage']` BUT this means that as soon as someone bookmarks the url that looks like this now:

www.example.com/page.php?cameFromHomePage=true

he or she can just go to the page.php using this link and it will always work.

Sessions are safer because no one but you can edit them, cookies are nice but depending on where you operate from you may need to show a cookie warning because of privacy laws, and the get request if it's just a "one time thing"

If you elaborate on why you want your users to go through the homepage frist, I can edit my answer and help you chose the best option.

Comment: since the OP is posting a form to page.php, the best option is to check the form has been posted. If you use sessions someone could still visit page.php with out posting the form.

Comment: Which is the point of the session,  you can fake a post,  but you can't fake a session,  the point it,  OP wants to check where the user comes from and the session,  cookie and other methods do just that, imo session is better simply because it can't be meddled with, one simple check for a user-defined session variable is far safer than a post check